# validator or mask for variable length number in angular2

Tags: angular

Is there a simple way to use variable length input string validation or masking in angular2.

Using the minlength and maxlength with number is not good choice, as it will allow to enter more than the required length in the input field. If we give input as text it can allow alphabets too. As in masking it will allow only required length and only digits if we provide but there is no provision for variable length like in our regular expression.

So I want to use regular expression kind thing so that I can mention what exactly the inputs will be and what the length range for the input too.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you can refer theese 
1.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-text-mask
2.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/@msafi/angular2-text-mask

Comment: I have already gone through all these but these are for constant length not for variable length.. I am just looking for a large range of length for the input.... For example the input may vary from single digit to 8 digits.  Thank you for your suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at msafi's answer to this issue https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/issues/174#issuecomment-244821737 ?

I used his function to make a mask of variable length similar to the one he posted and it worked. You just have to adapt the length checking to make it conform to your needs.